# Cannot change appearance of "{NewItemPlaceholder}" in WPF combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox, observablecollection

I have bound an `ObservableCollection<Company>` to a combobox.

```
<ComboBox 
    IsEditable="True" 
    Text="{Binding Path=Company.CompanyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CompanyCollection,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ucEventDialog}}}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Company}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

During runtime WPF adds at the end of the bound list an additional `ComboboxItem` `{NewItemPlaceHolder}` to the dropdown list.

I would like to use this item to trigger an additional dialog box to add a new item to the collection.

I tried to create a template for this additional item using `<ComboBox.Resources>` ...

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="PlaceholderTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="New..."/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

However I have not found any means to ...

1. Change the appearance of the `{NewItemPlaceHolder}`.
2. Trigger an event when the {NewItemPlaceHolder} is selected.

Comment: Please include the code that causes a `NewItemPlaceHolder` to be added to the `ComboBox`...

Comment: The `{NewItemPlaceHolder }` is added automatically without a single line of code when using a `ObservableCollection<>`.